# Design tips and best practices for visual navigation on mobile

Tags: mobile, navigation, design, dropdown

I'm designing a visual drop down menu something like this:

[image]

Any suggestions on how to adapt this for mobile and tablets? I'm struggling with balancing the imagery vs making it fast and functional. Anyone have any suggestions or ideas or examples of sites that do this well on mobile? Should I just sacrifice the visuals in the navigation on mobile and make it text based?

PS - you can see the current mobile navigation here: [www.fiercelymade.com](http://www.fiercelymade.com)

Thanks!

EDIT: So here's the final results:

http://www.fiercelymade.com/

Try it out on mobile and desktop.

I need to 1) tidy up the spacing and weighting on mobile - not happy with it right now and 2) make the desktop version less "jumpy". Any and all feedback on how to do this appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

I would say definitely sacrifice the images on mobile. Don't think of it as a sacrifice though, just an efficiency :-)

You'll never cater for the full breadth of mobile devices with a large menu and images - keep it simple and get the users where they want to go. By the looks of things the links have very concise titles so the images are just for aesthetic effect on bigger screens rather than to add clarity.

It's looking good though!

Comment: Agree: you don't really need the images in the nav. Check out Land's End ( http://www.landsend.com/ ) they use lots of imagery, but also maintain a robust responsive site.